# Is it a good practice to have a different favicon for each product of a company?

Tags: seo, favicon

There are 5 products(applications) produced by my company.

Is it a good practice to have a different favicon for each product?

Which is better: product-specific favicon or one favicon(company logo) for all 5 products?

Does product-specific favicon help SEO?

Please suggest the pros and cons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting. The favicons are used when someone bookmarks a page too - as long as you can maintain some kind of coherence in the style, then it should work well for the users - but clearly, for SEO the impact is nil.

You'll have better results from providing other meta data for individual pages (images, description, title, url etc..), but guess you're already up to speed there.